# Pandas assign a value to new row based on index on incoming live data

Tags: python, pandas

I am having trouble writing efficient code (without many loops) that assings a value to a cell in a pandas dataframe that is being updated every minute or so (live stream). In the training set I trained my model with one-hot encoded timestamp variables and it did better than continues variables, so that's what I want to use for production. The dataframe looks like this:

```
datetime              DOW_1     DOW_2    ... DOW_7    Month1   Month2   Month3 
`2018-07-01 09:30:00`  0          1            0         0       0        1
```

As you can see the columns are encoded with 0's and 1's to denote what month, day of week, (and I have more columns for day of year, is_holiday, etc...) I easily did this on training, validation, and test data using pd.get_dummies, but now that a live stream of data is coming in I cannot find an easy way to 'assign' month2 = 0 based on `df.index.month`

I tried doing something along the lines of this type of loop but it's quite tedious and slow..

```
i=0
while i < len(df):
    for m in range(1,13):
        if df.index.iloc[i].month == m:
            df['Month'+str(m)][i] = 1
            i+=1
        else:
            i+=1
```

Any better suggestions?

Comment: Is it possible that the line `df['Month'+str(m)][i] = i` should assing `1` instead of `i`?

Comment: Oops sorry typo.. Yep!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still thinking about a solution that removes even the for, but you can at least avoid the external while over `len(df)` using [.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
for m in range(1, 13):
    df.loc[df.index.month == m, 'Month'+str(m)] = 1
```

Comment: This is great - pretty much exactly what I was looking for. I don't know if there's a way to do it without any loops since some of the columns don't exist and they have to be created. The only last issue is it leaves the other columns with NaN values (i.e. month_1 has all 1's but month 2-12 has NaN's). Nice work, I'll mark it as correct!

Comment: Thanks. Regarding the NaN, you are right. I can think of 2 options to handle that: casting all NaN to zero, if possible: `df = df.fillna(0)` or adding a second line to the for filling the zeros:
`df.loc[df.index.month != m, 'Month'+str(m)] = 0` (note the `!=` instead of `==`). I couldn't figure out a completely for-free solution... I don't think it exists.

Comment: Nice! yeah the extra line makes more sense since I'm looping over a lot of columns